# Database visible in pgadmin but does not exist for other program

Tags: postgresql, vb6

I used the following code to create a database in postgresql.

```
Dim s1 As String
s1 = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=postgres;UID=username;PWD=pwd;CONNSETTINGS=SET Datestyle TO 'DMY'%3b;BOOLSASCHAR=0;TEXTASLONGVARCHAR=1;TrueIsMinus1=1;"
Dim c1 As New ADODB.Connection

c1.Open s1


Dim sDB_Name  As String
sDB_Name = "db1"

s1 = "CREATE DATABASE "" " & sDB_Name & """"
s1 = s1 & " With OWNER = postgres  "
s1 = s1 & " TEMPLATE = template0 "
s1 = s1 & " ENCODING = 'WIN1252' "
s1 = s1 & " TABLESPACE = pg_default "
s1 = s1 & " LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252' "
s1 = s1 & " LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252' "
s1 = s1 & " CONNECTION LIMIT = -1; "
c1.Execute s1
MsgBox "done"
Unload Me
```

It worked successfully insofar that with using pgadmin I can see and interact with this new database.

But when I try to work with this database via ADO from either the program that created the database or another program, I get the message :

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': FATAL: database "db1" does
>   not exist

If I create the same database with all the same properties using pgadmin then I don't get this
message and can work with the database using external programs.

Can somebody please explain what am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry just found out what I am doing wrong I am creating a database called " db1" rather than "db1". Stupid mistake. This line is worng :s1 = "CREATE DATABASE "" " & sDB_Name & """" should be s1 = "CREATE DATABASE """ & sDB_Name & """"

Comment: I thought about deleting the question but maybe it will be of some use to someone like me!!

Comment: You can answer your own question then accept it to close the question after a short delay.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, good idea. I have answered it now and can accept it in 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing wrong was that I was creating a database called

> " db1"

rather than

> "db1"

(there's a leading space in the name).

This line in the code was wrong :

```
s1 = "CREATE DATABASE "" " & sDB_Name & """"
```

It should have been

```
s1 = "CREATE DATABASE """ & sDB_Name & """"
```